# Need help to understand a theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request

I have been reading a theorem related with the existence of the outer generalized inverse of a matrix where i have certain difficulties to understand the theorem.

Theorem is as follows.

Let $A\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$, rank$(A) = r$, and let $T$ and $S$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{C^n}$ and $\mathbb{C^m}$, respectively, with $\dim (T )= \dim (S^\perp)=t\leq r$.

Then, $A$    has a $\{2\}$ - inverse X such that $R(X) = T$ and $N(X) = S$ iff one of the following condition is satisfied (where $R(X)$ and $N(X)$ denots the range and null space of $X$, respectively)

$AT\oplus S$ = $C^{m}$

$P_{S}{^\perp} AT = S^{\perp}$

$A^*S^\perp\oplus T^\perp$ = $C^{n}$

$P_T~ A^*S^\perp = T$

$\{2\}$ - inverse  of a matrix $A$ is a $n\times m$ matrix $X$ satisfying matrix equation $XAX = X$.

All above conditions are equivalent.

$P_{L.M}$ stands for the projection on to the space $L$ parallel to $M$ while $P_{L}$ stands for orthogonal projection onto sub space $L$ parallel to $L^\perp$.

Earlier i have posted same theorem where i was not clear about $AT$. Now that is cleared to me by answer given by David mitra .

I need a proper interpretation of these terms $P_{S}{^\perp} AT = S^{\perp}$, $P_T~ A^*S^\perp = T$, $A^*S^\perp$. it is given in the theorem that  $AT\oplus S$ = $C^{m}$ that means that there must exist projction operator $P_{AT}{S}$ .E projection onto subspace $AT$ parallel to $S$.
Also we have $dim (AT) = \dim S^\perp$.

I don't need proof.  It has some connection with direct sum of sub spaces and projection associated with that.

I just need their interpretation. I have to use this theorem for my own work. But how can i use if the things are not cleared to me? I really need help so that i can proceed further.

Heartily thanks for giving me your precious time.

Comment: No one has answered yet?

Comment: What is it that you denote by $R(X)$ and $N(X)$ ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy $R(X)$ and $N(X)$ denots the range and null space of $X$, respectively.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy I am not clear about certain things. I have mentioned them in mmy comments. I just need few clrifications. You deserve your bounty. Thanks for helping me out

Comment: I am sorry i have made few spelling mistakes(Mmy, clrifications)  . While it should be my and clarifications.

Comment: If I had something useful to say, I probably would have said it already. I find you e-mailing me to tell me to take a look at your post pretty annoying, especially given that my profile explicitly asks you not to do it. I hope you didn't do it to other people, and do **not** e-mail me again.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I am extremely sorry sir. I was completely unaware of that. I will never repeat it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us put $U=S^{\perp}$. I number your four statements from (1) to (4) :

$ {\rm (1) \ } AT\oplus S = {\mathbb C}^{m}$

$ {\rm (2) \ } P_{U} AT = U$

${\rm (3) \ }  A^*U\oplus T^\perp = {\mathbb C}^{n}$

${\rm (4) \ } P_T~ A^*U = T$

Let us show that those statements are all equivalent. It will suffice to show
that $(1) \Leftrightarrow (2)$, $(3) \Leftrightarrow (4)$ and  $ (1)  \Leftrightarrow (3) $.

$(1) \Rightarrow (2)$ : Suppose that (2) is true. Since $P_U$ is a projection onto $U$, we already have $P_{U} AT \subseteq U$. Now (1) implies that those two subspaces of
${\mathbb C}^m$ have the same dimension, so they are equal and (2) follows.

$(2) \Rightarrow (1)$ : Suppose that (2) is true. Then

$${\sf dim}(U)={\sf dim}(T) \geq {\sf dim}(AT) \geq {\sf dim}(P_UAT)={\sf dim} (U)$$

So all those dimensions are equal to ${\sf dim}(U)$. Let $c\in{\mathbb C}^m$. Then 
we can write $c=u+s$, with $u\in U,s\in S$. By (2) we have $u\in P_U(AT)$ also,
so there is a $t\in T$ such that $P_U(At)=u$. Then $At=u+s'$, for some $s'\in S$. 
So $c=At+s-s'$, and we have shown that ${\mathbb C}^m=AT+S$. This sum must in fact be direct because of the dimensions, and (1) follows.

We have thus shown that $(1) \Leftrightarrow (2)$. The proof of $(3) \Leftrightarrow (4)$ is similar, replacing $(A,T,U)$ with $(A^{*},U,T)$.

$(1) \Rightarrow (3)$ : Suppose that (1) is true. Let $v\in A^{*}S \cap T^{\perp}$. We have an $s\in S$ such that $v=A^{*}s$. Then $s\in S \cap (AT)=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$, so $v=0$. So $A^{*}S \cap T^{\perp}=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$, and those two subspaces of ${\mathbb C}^m$
must supplement each other because of the dimensions. So (3) follows.

$(3) \Rightarrow (1)$ : Suppose that (3) is true. If the subspace $AT+ S$ is not the whole of ${\mathbb C}^{m}$, there is a nonzero vector $w$ that's orthogonal to this subspace. Then $w$ is orthogonal to both $AT$ and $S$, and $A^{*}w \in T^{\perp} \cap (A^{*}S^{\perp})$. So $A^{*}w=0$. Since $w\in S^{\perp}$, we deduce ${\sf dim} (A^{*}S^{\perp})<{\sf dim} (S^{\perp})$. But then ${\sf dim} (A^{*}S^{\perp})+{\sf dim}(T^{\perp})<n$, and the sum in (3) cannot be direct.
This shows that $AT+ S={\mathbb C}^{m}$, and the sum must be direct because of the dimensions. QED

Comment: I am very much greatful to you. I have some queries. How to prove this  $P_{U} AT \subseteq U$ ? Can you  explain please?

Comment: I m not clear about these lines too;  Now (1) implies that those two subspaces of
${\mathbb C}^m$ have the same dimension, so they are equal . Explain me please.

Comment: I suppose here : By (2) we have $s\in P_U(AT)$ also: In place of s , u should be there?

Comment: @srijan : First question. $P_U$ is a projector onto $U$, so the image of this projector is $U$ : $P_U({\mathbb C}^m)=U$. Then $P_U(AT) \subseteq P_U({\mathbb C}^m)=U$.

Comment: @srijan : Second question. Those two subspaces have the same dimension, and one is contained into the other ($P_U(AT)$ is contained in $U$), so they are equal.

Comment: @srijan : Third question. You're right, I corrected my answer. Thanks.

Comment: This one is clear sir.

Comment: How to find dimension of  $P_{U} AT$? I am sorry i am not clear about this?

Comment: I think since $\dim (AT) = \dim (U)$ that means that $\dim P_{U}AT = \dim P_{U}$ which results in equality of dimensions of both the subspaces. Am i right?

Comment: @srijan : No, you're not right in your last comment. $P_U$ is an application so ${\sf dim}(P_U)$ is meaningless. What happens is that the kernel of $P_U$ is $U^{\perp}=S$, so $P_U$ is injective on $AT$ and hence ${\sf dim} P_U(AT)={\sf dim} (AT)$.

Comment: For  $1\Rightarrow 3$ ,i am not clear about this line: Let $v\in A^{*}S\cap T^{\perp}$. I think in place of $S$, $S^\perp$ should be there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3502/discussion-between-srijan-and-ewan-delanoy)

Comment: Certain things are not clear. These are 1: As i have mentioned above i am not clear about $1\Rightarrow 3$. I need little more explanation. 2:In $3\Rightarrow 1$ how can we be ensured that there is a nonzero vector $w$ orthogonal to subspace $AT\oplus S$. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Yes, in $1 \Rightarrow 3$, $S$ should be $S^{\perp}$. In $3 \Rightarrow 1$, take any orthogonal base $(e_1, \ldots ,e_r)$ of $AT+S$ and a vector $v\not\in (AT+S)$. Then $w=v-\sum_{k=1}^{r} <v,e_k>e_k$ is orthogonal to $AT+S$.